# How to add a color picker to my text field

Tags: php, jquery, html

Can anyone suggest me a best color picker for my CMS it should be text box when it get focus picker should display and color code of color should display in text box

Thanks in Advance

Comment: http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=color+picker+script

Answer (score 1):

You can find some demos and plugins here.

http://jqueryui.pbworks.com/ColorPicker

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [**http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/**](http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/)